# Как узнать, сколько раз игра была запущена?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу игру на юнити, и хочу сделать при первом входе в игру - обучение. Но я не могу отследить, сколько раз игра была запущена. Т.е. мне надо каким-то образом узнать, когда игрок запускает игру впервые. Не представляю, как это сделать.

Comment: Есть много разных способов, например вот:
https://habr.com/ru/post/163071/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество входов в игру не связано с обучением. Игра может быть запущена хоть 10 раз и выключена в меню.

```
public static class Test {
    private static bool _loaded;
    private static bool _firstTutorialIsCompleated;
    private static string _key = "FirstTutorialIsCompleated";

    private static void Load () {
        if (_loaded == false) {
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_key))
                _firstTutorialIsCompleated = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(_key) == 1;
            else {
                _firstTutorialIsCompleated = false;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt(_key, 0);
            }
            _loaded = true;
        }
    }

    public static bool FirstTutorialIsCompleated {
        get {
            Load();
            return _firstTutorialIsCompleated;
        }
    }

    public static void CompleatFirstTutorial () {
        _firstTutorialIsCompleated = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(_key, 1);
    }
}
//.....
if (Test.FirstTutorialIsCompleated == false)
    Debug.Log("Туториал не пройден");

Test.CompleatFirstTutorial(); // Туториал пройден
```